# prove H is a normal subgroup of D2n

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $n∈ \mathbb{Z}, \; n⩾3$ and $d∣n$. Let $r$ denote one of the rotations in $D_{2n}$ and $H =⟨r^d⟩$. 
1. Show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $D_{2n}$. 
2. If $d = 1$, show that $D_{2n}/H ≅ Z/2Z$.

for part 1, I think the first thing is to prove H is the subgroup of $D_{2n}$ then prove $H$ is normal, right? But after proving H is a subgroup of $D_{2n}$, I don't know how to start proving $H$ is normal. Should I just show that $g(r^d)g=r^d$ for every $g∈D_{2n}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know (and can use) that $\;\langle r\rangle\;$ is a normal subgroup of $\;D_{2n}\;$ ?

Comment: @Joanpemo do you mean let d=0? sorry, I suck on this topic

Comment: I'm not sure you really need to prove that $\langle r^d \rangle$ is a subgroup of $D_{2n}$ as the notation literally means "the subgroup generated by $r^d$." I assume that's something you can be trusted to use freely.

Comment: @pjs36 so for part 1, I just straightly prove H is normal?

Comment: I think that would be perfectly OK to take it for granted that $H$ is a subgroup, yeah, and just focus on showing that it's normal in $D_{2n}$.

Comment: @pjs36 just to how that g(r^d)g=r^d for every g∈G?

Comment: @Linda, that is not showing normality. You must show that for any $\;g\in G\;$ you have $\;g^{-1}r^dg=r^{kd}\;$ , for some integer $\;k\;$ .